# QTabWidget with multiple Tabs (QWidget). But the pushbutton, combobox in each Tab do not work

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer, qtabwidget

I use Qt Designer designed a QTabWidget with four Tabs(QWidget). Each Tab contains QPushButton,QComboBox,QTableWidget,etc. to achieve specific functions. For example, clicking Import dataset button is to select a excel from desktop to import excel data to present in a QTableWidget. Clicking Summary statistics button is to get statistics of the dataset to present in another QTableWidget. The ui file name is "mainInterface.ui". Then I load the ui file in PyCharm to run the codes. The question is that the QPushButton and other widges in each Tab do not work. How to make widges in each Tab work?

The layout in Qt Designer is shown in following figures.(currently, I am not allowed to embed a figure, thus it is a link.)
[layout of QTabWidget in Qt designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3nCy.jpg)

Following is the codes to load ui file and run codes.

```
# import modules
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas


# main body
class MainBody(QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainBody, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi("ui/mainInterface.ui")

# first tab, tab_dataset
class DatasetTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DatasetTab, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui.buttonImport.clicked.connect(self.ImportData)
        self.ui.buttonStatis.clicked.connect(self.SumStatis)

    # import dataset
    def ImportData(self):
        from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
        filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self.ui,      # 父窗口对象
            "choose the excel you want to import",  # title
            r"C:\Users\yy63t\Desktop",                    # initial contents
            "excel file types (*.xlsx *.xls)"                 # filter excel file types
        )

        if not filePath:
            return

        import xlrd
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(filePath)

        # sheet search starts from 0, the first sheet
        sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
        # define a global variable to used in other functions
        global sheet_excel
        sheet_excel = sheet1

        # obtain all rows and columns
        for i in range(0, sheet1.nrows):
            rowlist = sheet1.row_values(i)     # every row context
            # insert row in table widget
            row = self.ui.tableImport.rowCount()
            self.ui.tableImport.insertRow(row)

            for j in range(0, len(rowlist)):
                newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(rowlist[j]))
                self.ui.tableImport.setItem(row, j, newItem)

        # set table horizontal title/label
        label = sheet1.row_values(0)
        self.ui.tableImport.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(label)
        # remove the repeated header
        self.ui.tableImport.removeRow(1)

    # summary statistics of imported excel dataset
    def SumStatis(self):
        # total col number
        col_no = sheet_excel.ncols
        col_1 = sheet_excel.col_values(0)
        col_1_name = col_1[0]
        # remove the first element, the first element is variable name, a string
        col_1.pop(0)
        DF = pd.DataFrame({col_1_name : col_1})

        # start with 2nd col, add to dataframe
        for k in range(1, col_no):
            # the values of each column, col is a list
            col_k = sheet_excel.col_values(k)
            col_k_name = col_k[0]
            col_k.pop(0)
            DF[col_k_name] = col_k

        # statistics summary of dataframe
        # replace empty string with NaN. import excel, NaN is read as ' '
        DF1 = DF.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex = True)
        # define a global dataset to be used in other functions and tabs
        global DF_global
        DF_global = DF1
        DF_Statis = DF1.describe(include = 'all')
        print(DF_Statis)

        # add dataframe to tablewidgets
        # set table horizontal title/label
        label_H = sheet_excel.row_values(0)
        self.ui.tableStatis.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(label_H)
        # obtain all rows and columns
        for i in range(0, DF_Statis.shape[0]):
             for j in range(0, DF_Statis.shape[1]):
                newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(DF_Statis.iloc[i, j]))
                self.ui.tableStatis.setItem(i, j, newItem)

# second tab, tab_descrip
class DescripTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DescripTab, self).__init__(parent)

        # click button to plot
        self.ui.buttonPlot.clicked.connect(self.DescripPlot)
        # check property types change
        self.ui.comboBoxType.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.PropertyName)

        # set initial property name
        propertyType = self.ui.comboBoxType.currentText()
        if propertyType == 'Rock properties':
            self.ui.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.ui.comboBoxName.addItems(['porosity ', 'permeability', 'temperature', 'starting oil saturation'])

    # set property name when property types are changed
    def PropertyName(self):
        propertyType = self.ui.comboBoxType.currentText()
        if propertyType == 'Rock properties':
            self.ui.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.ui.comboBoxName.addItems(['porosity ', 'permeability', 'temperature', 'starting oil saturation'])
        elif propertyType == 'Oil properties':
            self.ui.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.ui.comboBoxName.addItems(['oil gravity ', 'oil viscosity', 'acid number', 'base number', 'asphaltene concentration'])
        elif propertyType == 'Water properties':
            self.ui.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.ui.comboBoxName.addItems(['salinity ', 'divalent cations concentration'])
        elif propertyType == 'Surfactant properties':
            self.ui.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.ui.comboBoxName.addItems(['surfactant concentration', 'surfactant type'])
        else:
            self.ui.comboBoxName.clear()
            self.ui.comboBoxName.addItems(['contact angle decrease', 'IFT reduction', 'improved oil recovery'])

    # descriptive plot
    def DescripPlot(self):
        # obtain current property name and rock type
        PropertyName_chosen = self.ui.comboBoxName.currentText()
        array_plot = DF_global[PropertyName_chosen].to_numpy()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.boxplot(array_plot)

        # put plot on QtWidgets
        self.ui.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(fig)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.content_plot)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.ui.plotWidget)

# execute
app = QApplication([])
window = MainBody()
window.ui.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Did you define `DatasetTab` as a promoted widget in `mainInterface.ui`?

Comment: Thanks so much. Finally, I solved the question at night.